# C# async and await not waiting for code to finish

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Why is the following `async` and `await` not working?  I am trying to learn this would like to understand what is wrong with my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        callCount();

    }

    static void count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("count loop: " + i);
        }
    }

    static async void callCount()
    {
        Task task = new Task(count);
        task.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Console.WriteLine("Writing from callCount loop: " + i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("just before await");
        await task;
        Console.WriteLine("callCount completed");
    }
}
```

The program goes starts the count() method but drops out without completing it.  With the await task; statement I was expecting it to wait to complete all loops of the count() method (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) before exiting.  I only get "count loop: 0".  But it is going through all of callCount().  Its like await task isn't doing anything.  I want both count() and callCount() to run asynchronously and return to main when complete.

Comment: If you don't `await` the result of `callCount`, then what do you think will happen?

Comment: copied your exact code in LinqPad and it did output all `count loop: x` 0..4

Comment: @MickyD You made a private class (I know OP did the same, but that's all that's wrong)

Comment: @MickyD maybe the private class is the problem - linqpad didn't need the class declaration

Comment: Program as posted will execute all loops, but only because  loop in `callCount` sleeps longer total time than loop in `count`. `Program` and `Main` can be private in .Net console app without a problem. @Arturo Menchaca has correct answer below.

Comment: @MickyD It's not broken. Try the same code in a console app...

Comment: @DavidG, sten, Hmm. Damn you dotnetfiddle.  By bad :)

Comment: Please see my response below to Arturo.  I tried that to no avail after seeing a similar question response here on stackoverflow.  With Task as the return type.  Why is "await task" not holding up exit from callCount until task (count()) is done?  I have even tried this:

Comment: @jaykum: In addition to avoiding `async void` and blocking the main thread in `Main` so the app doesn't exit, you should also never use the `Task` constructor or `Task.Start` (use `Task.Run` instead).

Comment: @StephenCleary I actually have been going through your blog on the subject and have tried the await Task.Run(() => count()); way but I have not been able to get both loops to run concurrently.  Depending on where I put the await, one or the other loop finishes before the other starts.  Probably something I am not doing correctly.  With Task.Start at the beginning of callCount and await at the end both loops start running.  Maybe I need to play around with it some more.  I feel honored to have an author like yourself addressing my concern, thanks.

Comment: You should be able to just replace `Task task = new Task(count); task.Start();` with `Task task = Task.Run(() => count());` and it should behave the same as the original code.

Comment: @StephenCleary that worked.  Thanks for the help.  I got the pointer to use the constructor from a C# Reference book.  Why is that a bad idea?

Comment: @jaykum: I explain why [task constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) and [`Task.Start`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html) are bad on my blog. With `Task` in particular, there's a big difference between what you *can* do and what you *should* do.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you execute an `async` method, it starts running synchronously until it reaches an `await` statement, then the rest of the code executes asynchronously, and execution return to the caller.

In your code `callCount()` starts running synchronously to `await task`, then back to `Main()` method, and since you are not waiting for the method to complete, the program ends without method `count()` can finish.

You can see the desired behavior by changing the return type to `Task`, and calling `Wait()` in `Main()` method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    callCount().Wait();
}

static void count()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("count loop: " + i);
    }
}

static async Task callCount()
{
    Task task = new Task(count);
    task.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Writing from callCount loop: " + i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("just before await");
    await task;
    Console.WriteLine("callCount completed");
}
```

**EDIT:**
This is how your code executes:

(for better understanding lets changes `CallCount()` return type to `Task`)

1. the program starts with `Main()` method.
2. `CallCount()` method is called.
3. the task is created, all this in the same thread.
4. Then the task is started. At this point, a new thread is created running `Count()` method in parallel.
5. Execution continues in CallCount(), for loop is executed and "just before await" is printed.
6. Then `await task;` is reached. This is when async-await pattern plays its role. `await` is not like `Wait()`, it doesn't block the current thread until the task finishes, but returns the execution control to the `Main()` method and all remaining instructions in `CallCount()` (in this case just `Console.WriteLine("callCount completed");`) will be executed after the task is completed.
7. In `Main()`, the call to `CallCount()` returns a `Task` (with the remaining instructions of `CallCount()` and the original task) and execution continues.
8. If you dont wait for this task to finishes, the execution in`Main()` will continue finalizing the program and the tasks being destroyed.
9. If you call `Wait()` (if `CallCount()` is void you dont have a task to wait for) you let the task to complete, holding in `Main()` for `Count()` execution and "callCount completed" being printed.

If you want to wait for count task finishes in `CallCount()` without returning to `Main()` method, call `task.Wait();`, all the program will wait for `Count()`, but this is not what `await` will do.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) explains async-await pattern in details.

Hopes this workflow diagram of your code helps you.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have tried it this way after seeing another similar question and response on stack overflow but it still does the same thing.  I did it exactly like you have with Task as the return type.

Comment: I see both my Writelines executing but its like it is ignoring "await task".  Shouldn't it hold up exit from callCount until count is done?

Comment: "When you execute an async method, it starts running synchronously until it reaches an await statement, then the rest of the code executes asynchronously, and execution return to the caller".  This does not seem true because once I do the task.Start() I am seeing alternating Writeline execution as if both count() and callCount() loops are running.  When I hit await task, my program exits count().

Comment: @jaykum I edited my answer to show how async-await pattern works in your code. When I says the method start running synchronously, I refering to Main() and CallCount() methods, not the task

Comment: Thank you very much Arturo for your detailed explanation and help.  I have finally understood the basics and got my program to work.  The key difference between await and wait() was important to grasp.  I have played around with it quite a bit now with your help.  I really appreciate everyone on stackoverflow being so generous with their time to help.  A great community.